# edit contact form 7 place holder

Tags: php, wordpress, contacts, contact-form-7

I am using contact form7 plugin for wordpress on my website for all forms.

Link of the form

1. http://highercodetechnolabs.com/contact-us/

Now I want to add some some font icon in to the field of the form like highercodetechnolabs dot com / test-contact

help me out as soon as poosible.

Following is the code I have written for the form customize

---

```
 <style>
 .wpcf7-form {
 background:#D8D8D8;
  border-radius:3px; 
  width:650px;
  padding: 8px 8px; 
   margin-
bottom:5px; 

 }

 </style>



 <style>
 #textarea {
   height: 40px;
    width: 270px;
   background:#FFFFFF;  moon-user; 
   border: medium none #089AE6;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  placeholder: moon-user;
 }

</style>

 <style>
 #textarea1 {
    height: 180px;
    width:600px;
   background:#FFFFFF
 }

 </style>
 <style>
 .wpcf7-submit { 
    background:#FA5858;

     border-top: none;
     border-bottom: none;
     border-left: none;
     border-right: none;
 border-radius: 0px; 
 width:220px;
    height:250px
 margin:7px 0;
 padding: 8px 8px;
 color:#fff; 
 font-size:20px
 }
 </style>

<style>
 table {border: none;}
 </style>

 <style>
 table, tr, td {
background: transparent;
 color: #000;

}
</style>

<style>

i
{
padding: 5px 10px;
display: inline-block;
-moz-border-radius: 100px;
-webkit-border-radius: 100px;
border-radius: 100px;
-moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 2px #888;
-webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 2px #888;
box-shadow: 0px 0px 2px #888;
}


</style>

<font color="#000000"  face="verdana" size="5">Your Contact Information</font>
<table>
<tr>
<td>[text* name id:textarea class:wpcf7-form placeholder   "* Your Name"]</td>

<td>[email* email id:textarea class:wpcf7-form placeholder "* Your Email"]</td>
</tr>

<table>
<tr>
<td>[tel* telephone id:textarea class:wpcf7-form placeholder "* Your Phone"]</td>
<td>[text companyname id:textarea class:wpcf7-form placeholder "Company Name"]</td>
</tr>
</table>

<table>
<tr>
 <td>
 [select* country id:textarea class:wpcf7-form "*Please Select Your Country" "Afghanistan" "Aland      
 Islands" "Albania" "Algeria" "American Samoa" "Andorra" "Angola" "Anguilla" "Antarctica"    
 "Antigua And Barbuda" "Argentina" "Armenia" "Aruba" "Australia" "Austria" "Azerbaijan" "Bahamas" 
 "Bahrain" "Bangladesh" "Barbados" "Belarus" "Belgium" "Belize" "Benin" "Bermuda" "Bhutan" 
 "Bolivia" "Bosnia And Herzegovina" "Botswana" "Bouvet Island" "Brazil" "British Indian Ocean 
 Territory" "Brunei Darussalam" "Bulgaria" "Burkina Faso" "Burundi" "Cambodia" "Cameroon" 
 "Canada" "Cape Verde" "Cayman Islands" "Central African Republic" "Chad" "Chile" "China"    
 "Christmas Island" "Cocos (Keeling) Islands" "Colombia" "Comoros" "Congo" "Congo, The Democratic 
 Republic Of The" "Cook Islands" "Costa Rica" "Cote D'Ivoire" "Croatia" "Cuba" "Cyprus" "Czech 
 Republic" "Denmark" "Djibouti" "Dominica" "Dominican Republic" "Ecuador" "Egypt" "El Salvador" 
 "Equatorial Guinea" "Eritrea" "Estonia" "Ethiopia" "Falkland Islands (Malvinas)" "Faroe Islands" 
 "Fiji" "Finland" "France" "French Guiana" "French Polynesia" "French Southern Territories" 
 "Gabon" "Gambia" "Georgia" "Germany" "Ghana" "Gibraltar" "Greece" "Greenland" "Grenada" 
"Guadeloupe" "Guam" "Guatemala" "Guernsey" "Guinea" "Guinea-Bissau" "Guyana" "Haiti" "Heard  
 Island And Mcdonald Islands" "Holy See (Vatican City State)" "Honduras" "Hong Kong" "Hungary" 
"Iceland" "India" "Indonesia" "Iran, Islamic Republic Of" "Iraq" "Ireland" "Isle Of Man" "Israel" 
"Italy" "Jamaica" "Japan" "Jersey" "Jordan" "Kazakhstan" "Kenya" "Kiribati" "Korea, Democratic 
 People'S Republic Of" "Korea, Republic Of" "Kuwait" "Kyrgyzstan" "Lao People'S Democratic 
 Republic" "Latvia" "Lebanon" "Lesotho" "Liberia" "Libyan Arab Jamahiriya" "Liechtenstein" 
  "Lithuania" 
 "Luxembourg" "Macao" "Macedonia, The Former Yugoslav Republic Of" "Madagascar" "Malawi" 
 "Malaysia" 

"Maldives" "Mali" "Malta" "Marshall Islands" "Martinique" "Mauritania" "Mauritius" "Mayotte"    
"Mexico" 
 "Micronesia, Federated States Of" "Moldova, Republic Of" "Monaco" "Mongolia" "Montserrat" 
"Morocco" 
 "Mozambique" "Myanmar" "Namibia" "Nauru" "Nepal" "Netherlands" "Netherlands Antilles" "New    
  Caledonia" 
  "New Zealand" "Nicaragua" "Niger" "Nigeria" "Niue" "Norfolk Island" "Northern Mariana Islands" 

  "Norway" "Oman" "Pakistan" "Palau" "Palestinian Territory, Occupied" "Panama" "Papua New   
  Guinea" 
  "Paraguay" "Peru" "Philippines" "Pitcairn" "Poland" "Portugal" "Puerto Rico" "Qatar" "Reunion" 
 "Romania" "Russian Federation" "Rwanda" "Saint Helena" "Saint Kitts And Nevis" "Saint Lucia" 
 "Saint Pierre And Miquelon" "Saint Vincent And The Grenadines" "Samoa" "San Marino" "Sao Tome 
 And Principe" "Saudi Arabia" "Senegal" "Serbia And Montenegro" "Seychelles" "Sierra Leone" 
 "Singapore" "Slovakia" "Slovenia" "Solomon Islands" "Somalia" "South Africa" "South Georgia And 
 The South Sandwich Islands" "Spain" "Sri Lanka" "Sudan" "Suriname" "Svalbard And Jan Mayen" 
 "Swaziland" "Sweden" "Switzerland" "Syrian Arab Republic" "Taiwan, Province Of China" 
 "Tajikistan" "Tanzania, United Republic Of" "Thailand" "Timor-Leste" "Togo" "Tokelau" "Tonga" 
 "Trinidad And Tobago" "Tunisia" "Turkey" "Turkmenistan" "Turks And Caicos Islands" "Tuvalu" 
 "Uganda" "Ukraine" "United Arab Emirates" "United Kingdom" "United States" "United States Minor 
 Outlying Islands" "Uruguay" "Uzbekistan" "Vanuatu" "Venezuela" "Viet Nam" "Virgin Islands, 
 British" "Virgin Islands, U.S." "Wallis And Futuna" "Western Sahara" "Yemen" "Zambia" 
 "Zimbabwe"]
  </td></tr>
  </table>

 <font color="#000000" face="verdana" size="5">Brief Project Description</font>
 [textarea* requirement 20x20 id:textarea1 class:wpcf7-form]


 [submit class:wpcf7-submit "SUBMIT INQUIRY"]</a>

 <img src="http://highercodetechnolabs.com/hct/1401538223_MB__LOCK.png" height="42" width="42"    
 align="middle"><font color="#000000" size="4">&nbsp;<b>WE GUARANTEE 100% SECURITY OF YOUR   
 INFORMATION</font></b>

 <font color="#000000" size="2">We will not share the details you provide above with anyone. Your        
 email won't be used for spamming.
```

---

Please help me out @ info@highercodetechnolabs.com

Answer (score 0):

**Solution 1: absolute positioning hack**

You can load the custom font just before the input field, and then force it to the right and then just position the placeholder text properly inside using padding.

See this answer https://teamtreehouse.com/forum/how-do-i-put-icons-inside-of-input-fields on Treehouse, it may give you some good clues for a solution that fits your problem.

http://jsbin.com/xexuwi/1/edit for a working example!

**Solution 2: replace with background images**

You are using some custom fonts to try to get the icons in, but if it's not working for you, maybe try to set the icons as background images instead.

See my http://jsbin.com/gakaye/3/edit solution for a working example.

I carved up the icon image, uploaded it, then set it as a background image with specific positioning. You can set it to whatever element you need (to have different backgrounds for different fields).